# why does my UITableView not appear to start in editing = YES mode when initialized?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewController subclass.  I set `self.editing = YES` at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method, but when the table is displayed the little red 'delete' icon does not appear next to each row.

Then, I added an edit button to the navigation item:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

When I launch the application now, it starts in edit mode (I can tell because the edit button says 'done') but, again, the delete icons don't appear.  Then if I toggle it with the edit button twice (once to turn it off, then once to turn it on), the red delete icons appear.

So, my question is: why aren't the table cells displaying correctly when first displayed?  I've tried moving the `self.editing = YES` line to other places in the code, like in the `init` function or the `viewWillAppear` function, but no dice.  It seems like this is a result of funny ordering somewhere (e.g. table cells initialized before editing is set, or something), but I can't figure it out; running the debugger shows that the `viewDidLoad` call happens before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as one would expect.

Other notes:

- Yes, I am having `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`.  But from debugging I've verified that that function is not even called after the first load.  (It gets called after I toggle editing mode twice.)

Comment: you call "self.editing = YES" on UITableViewController subclass... shouldn't you be doing that to the TableView object (self.tableView.editing = YES)..?  also try putting it in viewDidAppear

Comment: self.tableView vs. self has no effect.  moving to viewDidAppear worked though--thanks!!  More discussion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d'oh, adding it in `viewDidAppear` (or, better: `viewWillAppear`) did the trick.  Thanks @lukya and @willcodejavaforfood for suggestions.

I feel silly.  I swear I thought I'd checked that.

Moral of the story: setting the editing property too early makes page elements not display in editing mode.  (Doesn't that seem like a bug?)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
```

method in UITableView

Comment: switching to the setEditing:animated message had no effect, but it was an interesting suggestion (makes sense that the edit button would call that message, and that this message *could* do stuff in addition to setEditing:(BOOL)editing).